# Will perl 5.8.4 scripts work with perl 5.16.3?

Tags: perl

Will perl 5.8.4 scripts work with perl 5.16.3?

I was trying to install perl in CentOS 7. Default version seems to be 5.16.

Will perl 5.8.4 scripts work correctly in 5.16?

This is what I tried. Looks like default version is 5.16. Hence the question.

```
sudo yum install perl

================================================================================
 Package                    Arch       Version                   Repository
                                                                           Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 perl                       x86_64     4:5.16.3-294.el7_6        base     8.0 M
Installing for dependencies:
 perl-Carp                  noarch     1.26-244.el7              base      19 k
 perl-Encode                x86_64     2.51-7.el7                base     1.5 M
 perl-Exporter              noarch     5.68-3.el7                base      28 k
 perl-File-Path             noarch     2.09-2.el7                base      26 k
 perl-File-Temp             noarch     0.23.01-3.el7             base      56 k
 perl-Filter                x86_64     1.49-3.el7                base      76 k
 perl-Getopt-Long           noarch     2.40-3.el7                base      56 k
 perl-HTTP-Tiny             noarch     0.033-3.el7               base      38 k
 perl-PathTools             x86_64     3.40-5.el7                base      82 k
 perl-Pod-Escapes           noarch     1:1.04-294.el7_6          base      51 k
 perl-Pod-Perldoc           noarch     3.20-4.el7                base      87 k
 perl-Pod-Simple            noarch     1:3.28-4.el7              base     216 k
 perl-Pod-Usage             noarch     1.63-3.el7                base      27 k
 perl-Scalar-List-Utils     x86_64     1.27-248.el7              base      36 k
 perl-Socket                x86_64     2.010-4.el7               base      49 k
 perl-Storable              x86_64     2.45-3.el7                base      77 k
 perl-Text-ParseWords       noarch     3.29-4.el7                base      14 k
 perl-Time-HiRes            x86_64     4:1.9725-3.el7            base      45 k
 perl-Time-Local            noarch     1.2300-2.el7              base      24 k
 perl-constant              noarch     1.27-2.el7                base      19 k
 perl-libs                  x86_64     4:5.16.3-294.el7_6        base     688 k
 perl-macros                x86_64     4:5.16.3-294.el7_6        base      44 k
 perl-parent                noarch     1:0.225-244.el7           base      12 k
 perl-podlators             noarch     2.5.1-3.el7               base     112 k
 perl-threads               x86_64     1.87-4.el7                base      49 k
 perl-threads-shared        x86_64     1.43-6.el7                base      39 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+26 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 11 M
Installed size: 36 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: N
```

Comment: Without seeing the script, we can't tell. 5.8.4 is from 2004, 5.16.3 is from 2013, that's nine years of development. But the differences shouldn't be substantial, Perl tries to keep backward compatibility where possible.

Comment: There are around 10/11 small scripts and a couple of larger scripts. Mostly for formatting data, like shifting columns in a csv, adding prefixes to column entries etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably. Perl puts a lot of effort into maintaining backwards compatibility and most things will probably work. Having said that, there have been things that have changed which will potentially cause problems. The best solution is to set up a test environment with the new version of Perl and to run your test suite there. If you don't have a test suite, then the best idea is to not change anything at all until you have written a test suite!

I'm a little concerned that you're running `yum install perl`. Centos 7 comes with Perl installed as default. You shouldn't have to install it. You might, however, like to run `yum install perl-core` to ensure that you have a full Perl environment available.

Comment: I am using a CentOS minimal install VM. That's why no pre-installed Perl.

Comment: Is it possible at all to install same 5.8.4 in CentOS 7 manually since yum will always get the latest version?

Comment: @CornerH: You could use something like [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) to install a different version of Perl. But I'd strongly recommend upgrading to a newer version of Perl over installing an older version. 5.8.4 was released over 15 years ago.

Comment: Not sure about perlbrew,  believe it might be perceived as unsafe in a production environment. But, it makes sense to go with the newer version of Perl. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Perl is almost always backwards compatible. That's its biggest strength and at the same the time its biggest problem.